# Converting a range in excel to a single column with excel vba

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I am very new to coding and know only the basics.  The first part of this code is running fine.  It converts a range of values to a single column.  However, with my data set the rows of data step down, as shown in the sample data set below, so that when they are converted to a single column there are large gaps of 0 values in the column.  I added a portion of code to the end to look at each cell in the column and delete any 0 values.  The problem is this code takes around 4-5 hours to run.  I am hoping there is a better way to write the code to speed up the processing time.

Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub CombineColumns()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Dim rng As Range
Dim iCol As Long
Dim lastCell As Long
Dim k As Long

k = 484
'set K equal to the number of data points that created the range


Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
lastCell = rng.Columns(1).Rows.Count + 1

For iCol = 2 To rng.Columns.Count
    Range(Cells(1, iCol), Cells(rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count, iCol)).Cut
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Cells(lastCell, 1)
    lastCell = lastCell + rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count

Next iCol
Dim z As Long
Dim m As Long


z = k ^ 2

For row = z To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(row, 1) = 0 Then
    Range("A" & row).Delete Shift:=xlUp

   Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & row & " of z: " & Format((z - row) / z, "Percent")
   DoEvents

    End If

Next

Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


End Sub
```

[image: Sample Dataset]

Comment: 4-5 Hours with `ScreenUpdating`, `Events`, & `Calculation` all disabled. Just how large **is** your data set?

Answer (score 1):

### 4-5 hours is ridiculous

4-5 hours with `ScreenUpdating`, `Events`, & `Calculation` disabled is even more so.

What you've discovered here is that Excel is **very** slow at inserting/deleting columns/rows when you have large amounts of data in a Worksheet.

and you're doing it up to **235,000 times**.

---

### Delete everything in a single operation

What we're going to do here is loop through Ranges and, as we go, add all the Ranges-to-be-deleted to one master Range using the `Union()` function.

Then, at the end, delete the entire master range in one go:

```
Dim rowsToBeDeleted As Range '/ our master delete range

For row = Z To 1 Step -1

    If Cells(row, 1) = 0 Then

        If rowsToBeDeleted is Nothing Then '/ check if any ranges have been added yet
            Set rowsToBeDeleted = Range("A" & row) '/ add the first range
        Else
            Set rowsToBeDeleted = Union(rowsToBeDeleted, Range("A" & row)) '/ add the new range to the existing ones
        End If

    End If

Next row

If Not rowsToBeDeleted Is Nothing Then '/ check that we found anything to delete
    rowsToBeDeleted.EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

I suspect that this change alone will take your runtime from hours to minutes.

(Just as an aside, worth noting that a `Range` object can only have up to 1,048,576 range areas. So if you ever get up to more than 1,024^2, you'll have to check against it.)

Answer (score 1):

"Copy(or Cut)&Paste" operations as well as "Deleting rows" ones are expensive operations in Excel UI.

And since "Cut row" means "Delete row", then "Cut&Paste" is a most expensive one!

So the best would be avoid both!

Let's see how to do that

---

**Avoiding Copy(or Cut)&Paste**

Since you're dealing with *numbers*, I assume your real concern is for their *values*, so you can bother `.Value` property of `Range` object only,
rather then with cells fonts or backcolors (and all that jazz)

This means you can benefit from a very *cheap* statement like the following:

```
Range1.Value = Range2.Value
```

where you only have to make sure that both ranges have the same size

in your case this could be coded as:

```
With Range(Cells(1, iCol), Cells(rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count, iCol))
    Cells(lastCell, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
End With
```

thus leaving you with all those copied values to be deleted

for this task we can make use of the `.ClearContent()` method of `Range` object which, again, only deals with cell `.Value` property (as opposite to `.Clear()` method which is much more expensive since it deals with all `Range` object properties).

So that we could be tempted to just add a statement within our `With` block, which is just referring to the wanted (copied) range:

```
With Range(Cells(1, iCol), Cells(rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count, iCol))
    Cells(lastCell, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
    .ClearContents
End With
```

Though syntactically correct, this approach isn't the fastest being that *clearance* made through many (as the columns are) statements

It's better to make a one-shot clearance:

```
With Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion
    '
    'loop code
    '
    Intersect(.Cells.Offset(, 1), .Cells).ClearContents '<--| clear the copied cells 
End With
```

where you clear the cells:

- belonging to the "original" `CurrentRegion` of `Cell(1,1)`
  since the `With` block keeps referring to the range as it was set at that moment, ignoring subsequent changes (all those pasted values down its first column)
- offsetted by 1

  to avoid first column of "original" `CurrentRegion` of `Cell(1,1)`
- intersecting with itself

  to avoid clearing columns out of the "original" `CurrentRegion` of `Cell(1,1)`

---

**Avoid Deleting Rows**

But *the best is yet to come!*

being your data structure as per your example you can avoid pasting blank values, and so having to delete them by the end as well

just limit the values-to-be-copied range down to its last non empty row, substituting:

```
With Range(Cells(1, iCol), Cells(rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count, iCol))
```

with:

```
With Range(Cells(1, iCol), Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp))
```

In fact

`rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count`

always refers to the same rows number, namely the rows number of `rng`, so that not always it could substituted with a constant but it doesn't account for the current column actual non-empty cells number

While:

`Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp)`

always follows the current column last non-empty cell

This way you won't have any blank cell copied into `rng` first column and therefore no rows to delete at all!

---

**Use `With` keyword for full qualified range references**

This is a golden rule for the following reasons:

1. avoids ranges misreferences

   coding:

   `Worksheets("MySheetName").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion`

   makes you sure to reference the `CurrentRegion` of `Range` "A1" of "MySheetName" worksheet

   while:

   ```
   Range(Cells(1, iCol), Cells(rng.Columns(iCol))
   ```

   actually has VBA refer to the *active* worksheet for all `Range` and `Cells` objects and to `rng` for `Columns` object.

   this could still be correct and easy to follow when the code is short enough and hasn't any `Select`/`Selection` and/or `Activate`/`Active` operations, nor opens any new workbook. Otherwise all those operations would soon lead to loose the *active* worksheet knowledge and range reference control
2. Speed up code

   since it avoids VBA te task to resolve a `Range` reference down to its root when unnecessary

---

**Summary**

all what above may result in the following "core"-code:

```
Sub CombineColumns()
    Dim iCol As Long

    With Worksheets("MySheetName").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        For iCol = 2 To .Columns.Count
            With .Range(.Cells(1, iCol), .Cells(.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp))
                .Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
            End With
        Next iCol
        Intersect(.Cells.Offset(, 1), .Cells).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

that you can combine with those application setting-on/offs (especially those about `Calculation`) and some user information like follows:

```
Sub CombineColumns()
    Dim iCol As Long

    TurnSettings False               
    With Worksheets("MySheetName").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        For iCol = 2 To .Columns.Count
            Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & iCol & " of: " & .Columns.Count & " (" & Format((.Columns.Count - iCol) / .Columns.Count, "Percent") & ")"
            With .Range(.Cells(1, iCol), .Cells(.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp))
                .Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
            End With
        Next iCol
        Intersect(.Cells.Offset(, 1), .Cells).ClearContents
    End With    
    TurnSettings True
End Sub

Sub TurnSettings(boolSetting As Boolean)
    With Application
        .StatusBar = Not boolSetting
        .ScreenUpdating = boolSetting
        .EnableEvents = boolSetting
        .Calculation = IIf(boolSetting, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Zanwigz, did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider an SQL solution using the UNION query of `NOT NULL` columns and avoid any loop, screen controls, or range references. To set up, simply give your columns names (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...) in a DATA worksheet, and an empty RESULTS worksheet. Do note this would only work for Excel for PC as it connects to the JET/ACE SQL Engine (Window .dll files) via ADO interface.

```vb
Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
Dim i As Integer

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' TWO CONNECTION STRINGS
'    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
'                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm;"
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                   & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _
                   & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"

strSQL = " SELECT [DATA$].Col1 As SingleColumn FROM [DATA$] WHERE [DATA$].Col1 IS NOT NULL" _
            & " UNION ALL SELECT [DATA$].Col2 FROM [DATA$] WHERE [DATA$].Col2 IS NOT NULL" _
            & " UNION ALL SELECT [DATA$].Col3 FROM [DATA$] WHERE [DATA$].Col3 IS NOT NULL" _
            ' ...add more columns...

' OPEN WORKBOOK CONNECTION
conn.Open strConnection
rst.Open strSQL, conn

' COLUMN HEADERS
For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(1, i) = rst.Fields(i - 1).Name
Next i

' DATA ROWS
Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

rst.Close: conn.Close
Set rst = Nothing Set conn = Nothing
```